# How to know what makes ubuntu shut down?

Tags: power-management, shutdown

I leave my machine a while. After I come back , I find machine shut down.

How to know what makes my machine shut down? I do NOT shut down it manually.

I use ubuntu12.04.2 amd64 arch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a laptop? if so, I have a funny feeling that perhaps your computer is not shutting down is simply going into hibernation or sleep mode! What do you do after you come back to turn your computer back on? Are you hitting enter, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>del</kbd> or power button, perhaps just pushing the power button very gently will bring your computer back on from hibernation/sleep mode.

Comment: Thanks, I am SURE that is NOT hibernation or sleep.